# Update attribute data-id for li element Nestable don't update

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, jquery-ui-sortable

I has problem with Nestable.
When i use

```
var updateOutput = function (e) {
var list = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
    output = list.data('output');
if (window.JSON) {
    output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize'))); //, null, 2));
} else {
    output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
}
```

};

```
$('#element').attr({'data-id':'newvalue'});
updateOutput($('.nestable').data('output', $('#nestable_list_output')));
```

I don't see output change. When i view our via chrome i see data-id of that element changed.
Please help me.
This is full soure

```
function Update_This_Menu(){
$('.update-this-menu').click(function(){
    var RootElement = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    var NameMenu = RootElement.find('.NameThisMenu').val();
    var TitleMenu = RootElement.find('.TitleThisMenu').val();
    if(NameMenu == ''){
        RootElement.find('.NameThisMenu').addClass('parsley-error');
    }
    else {
        RootElement.data({'name':NameMenu});
        RootElement.data({'title':TitleMenu});
        updateOutput($('.nestable').data('output', $('#nestable_list_output')));
        RootElement.find('.form-edit-menu').hide('slow');
    }

});
}
```

This is function remove MENU is OK

```
function Remove_Menu(){
$('.remove-this-menu').click(function(){
    var RootElement = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    RootElement.remove();
    updateOutput($('.nestable').data('output', $('#nestable_list_output')));
});
}
```

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('#element').data('id','newvalue');
```

Comment: Element changed but output of nestable does not change

Comment: It will not appear in html you are inspecting through firebug.try logging value in console or alerting it to verify the changes